# Multi select the elements and remove attribute within element and document click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a condition where I have to **multi-select** elements and change there color when they are selected.
I want to remove the color on document click and also on  element click , so what ever things are selected there color come back to there original color when clicked on document . Right now I am able to achieve this only on element using ToggleClass.
This is what I have tried so far.

```js
$('.Current').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');

});
```

```css
a:visited,
a:focus {
  color: #000
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.Current {
  width: 100%;
  background: #7bd4ff;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.Current.selected {
  background: #ffadc9
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
```

i want to remove color of elements on document click too. 
Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least two ways to do it:

#### With another click handler

You'll need to:

1. Prevent the bubbling of the click from within your `.Current` elements, via `stopPropagation`.
2. Add a click handler to `document` that clears the class, e.g. `$(document).on("click", ...)`
3. Make sure there's part of the document available for clicking (probably by making `body` extend the full height of the viewport (`html, body { height: 100% }`).

Example:

```js
$('.Current').click(function(e) {   // Note `e`
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on("click", function() {
  $(".selected.Current").removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
a:visited,
a:focus {
  color: #000
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.Current {
  width: 100%;
  background: #7bd4ff;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.Current.selected {
  background: #ffadc9
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
```

#### With a single document-level click handler

You can combine the actions of the two click handlers into one if you like, by checking whether the click travelled through a `.Current` before reaching `document`. But this has the issue that if the click is handled by other elements en route to `document`, it may have side-effects you don't want.

Example:

```js
$('.Current').click(function(e) {   // Note `e`
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  var current = $(e.target).closest(".Current");
  if (current[0]) {
      current.toggleClass("selected");
  } else {
      $(".selected.Current").removeClass("selected");
  }
});
```

```css
a:visited,
a:focus {
  color: #000
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.Current {
  width: 100%;
  background: #7bd4ff;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.Current.selected {
  background: #ffadc9
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("div.current").removeClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: It may be more useful for other people to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Select document event and remove 'selected' class from required element.
Also add css (display block) to `<a>` so we get pointer all over the element.

```js
$('.Current').click(function(e) {  
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $(".selected.Current").removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
a:visited,
a:focus {
  color: #000
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.Current {
  width: 100%;
  background: #7bd4ff;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.Current.selected {
  background: #ffadc9
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
<div class="Current"><a href="#">Click Event Color Change</a></div>
```